# Emacs-Haskell Mode: How do I show the errors?

Tags: haskell, emacs

I am editing Haskell in Emacs.  I have `haskell-mode` enabled, and have "loaded" the file with `haskell-process-load-file`; now I have markers in the fringe, such as a question mark, e.g.

```
? import Debug.Trace ( trace, traceShow )
```

(the above is an approximation; the `?` is in the "fringe", and so rendered differently (lower dpi)).

My question is, how do I see the error-or-warning that the `?` relates to?  I can move between such marks with `haskell-goto-next-error` and `haskell-goto-prev-error`, but I can never see the error/warning message.

Bonus points if there's a programmatic way to see the error, such that I could interrogate it and perhaps act on it (e.g., for an unused import, I could parse the message and remove the import in question).

I have LSP-mode enabled too; I have tried disabling that and re-loading, but it makes no difference.

I have flycheck-mode enabled too; I have tried disabling that and re-loading, but it makes no difference.  I had already been through the flycheck errors & warnings, and cleaned those up.

Comment: you can call `display-local-help` when you're on the squiggles - or set `help-at-pt-display-when-idle`, programmatically you can do what that function does, calling `(help-at-pt-kbd-string)`, or get the message directly by extracting it from the `haskell-msg` overlay there (iterate over the overlays)

Comment: Thank you very much for this, @Rorschach, with this & a little keybinding, I'm in business.  I can extract the messages from the overlay, and I can set `help-at-pt-display-when-idle`, but even having turned off `haskell-doc-mode`, still the haskell doc supercedes the error messages, and even when I hit `display-local-help', it shows for a second and then shows the `haskell-doc` stuff.  Any clues for making the error message show by default, and only show the `haskell-doc` if there is no error, would be much appreciated.

Comment: so the haskell-doc message is coming from eldoc, right? If you call `display-local-help` interactively, I dont think eldoc should be displaying any messages, at least in emacs >v28. I'm not sure of a simple way to force eldoc to respect error messages without advising one of the functions.  I dont see the same behaviour as you- for me the messages displayed alternate b/w haskell-doc & errors after each interactive command, eg. `forward-char`, and dont seem to clobber eachothers

Comment: Well, disabling eldoc makes no observable difference; whereas disabling haskell-doc does.

No worries, thanks for the pointers, I'll play around, try a new emacs and perhaps eglot.

Comment: in that case, since you said you have lsp enabled, my guess is you also have `lsp-eldoc-render-all` or `lsp-signature-render-documentation` set to `t`.  You could try disabling one of those, and if that works, you could let bind it around `display-local-help`.  You could try `debug-on-message` to get a backtrace to see what is causing the clobber if neither of those work